# ng-click executes multiple times in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been facing an unexpected issue. Here is my code

```
<li ng-repeat="(key,product) in products">
   <div class="avl-box">
     <a href="javascript:void();" ng-click="showDetail(product.item_id);">
         <img ng-src="{{SITEURL}}files/item/f_image/{{key}}/{{product.f_image}}" width="1000" height="1000" alt="">
     </a>
   </div>
</li>
```

In my products array, I've `3` products. All things are working fine even `ng:click();`  too. But my issue is why `ng:click` executes `three` times when I click `once` ? I've searched it a lot but nothing works for me. The same issue I'd with `ng-options` and `ng-change` together. See below example -

```
<select class="form-control dropDownPercent" name="demo" ng-model="CampaignsService.percentModel[$index]" ng-change="CampaignsService.showChange(CampaignsService.percentModel[$index], $index)" ng-options="o as o for o in CampaignsService.percentDropDownOptions[$index].values">
```

Options were coming properly, in this drop down I'd `10` items to display, but when I chose one then `showChange` function did execute `10` times. Can anyone help me?

Comment: can you create a fiddle/plnkr that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a reason behind the failure of my code after a long walk. The reason was, I was calling a function in one of my expression and that was

```
<div class="slide3-price"> {{showDetail().item_price | currency}} </div>
```

and my function was

```
$scope.showDetail = function (prod_id) {

            if (typeof prod_id === 'undefined') {
                prod_id = 27;
            }
            //logical code
            return {
                'colors': json.campaign_data.Product[prod_id].Color,
                'prod_title': this.val,
                'f_image': json.campaign_data.Product[prod_id].f_image,
                'item_id': prod_id,
                'item_price': json.campaign_data.Product[prod_id].price
            }

        }
```

So binding a function in expression forces that function to be reevaluated for the every item on every digest. Instead of calling a function in an expression, I created an array of values and use them in template. Like

```
<div class="slide3-price"> {{campaignDetailDescription['item_price'] | currency}} | currency}} </div>
```

But to prevent multiple times calling a function we need to `add a watch listener to this variable` or `add a counter vairable`. I made a counter and now my function looks like

```
$scope.showDetail = function (prod_id) {

            var counter = 0;

            if (counter === 0) {

                if (typeof prod_id === 'undefined') {
                    $scope.setItemId();
                } else {
                    $scope.item_id2 = prod_id;
                }

                $scope.gettitle($scope.item_id2);

                $scope.campaignDetailDescription['colors'] = $scope.json.campaign_data.Product[$scope.item_id2].Color;
                $scope.campaignDetailDescription['prod_title'] = $scope.val;
                $scope.campaignDetailDescription['f_image'] = $scope.json.campaign_data.Product[$scope.item_id2].f_image;
                $scope.campaignDetailDescription['item_id'] = $scope.item_id2;
                $scope.campaignDetailDescription['item_price'] = $scope.json.campaign_data.Product[$scope.item_id2].price;

            }
            counter++;
        }
```

Now my function is executing only once for `ng-click`. Thanks to `SO`.

Answer (score 0):

The classic Javascript way to avoid multiple click events being fired is to wrap your code in a timeout. The angular version of this, is:

```
var timer;
function showDetail() {
  if (timer) {
      $timeout.cancel(timer);
  }
  timer = $timeout(function() {
      // your code
  }, 1000);
}
```

If a second onClick event is fired within a second, it will be cancelled.

Although, it would be useful if we could see a plunkr, as the behaviour you are describing is not normal. Use the above code as a last resort, only.