# angularJs filter in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-directive

I am trying to provide a pagination to a table:
Let's say there are `100` records and **records per page** is `10`. If I am in 3rd page, records from `21` to `30` should be prepared in the table.

So I am trying to filter those records using `angular filter` but couldn't succeed. 
I tried multiple ways:

1. `<tr on-last-repeat ng-repeat="record in data | filter:( $index>= fromRow && $index <= toRow)" role="row">`
2. Created a custom filter but unable to pass either `$index` or record to the `filter`. If record could be passed to the filter, so that I can get the index by `records.indexOf(record)`.

Trying to pass `$index`:

```
<tr on-last-repeat ng-repeat="record in data | paging:$index:fromRow:toRow track by $index" role="row">
```

I found a solution in `StackOverflow` which is named as native filter:

```
<tr on-last-repeat ng-repeat="record in data | filter:filterPaging()" role="row">

$scope.filterPaging = function(){
    return function(record){
        var idx = $scope.data.indexOf(record)+1;
        if(idx >= $scope.fromRow && idx <= $scope.toRow) return true;
        return false;
    }
};
```

But this function is getting called so many times. My table has 4 columns and 10 records and the function is being called for 40 times. I am concerning about performance if there are thousands of records.

Can somebody please take few minutes to have a look on this.

Comment: It may help you but not much sure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750068/ng-click-executes-multiple-times-in-ng-repeat

Comment: Do you know there is built-in [`limitTo`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) filter? Btw. on our projects we always ended up filtering arrays on-demand in the controller so that the ngRepeat does not use any filters.

Comment: @PavelHoral Well no, I have never heard. Thanks, it worked well. BTW, still I am curious to know if there is any way to pass either `$index` or looped `item` to filter. Can you keep the comment as answer so that I can mark it as 'Accepted'.

Comment: Unfortunately the filter works before any child scope (hence `$index` or *item*) is created. So no, you can not use those in the `ngRepeat` expression.

Comment: it is happening because your filter method is getting call on each digest call..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is built-in [`limitTo`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) filter doing exactly what you are trying to achieve.

By the way on our projects we always ended up filtering arrays on-demand in the controller (or custom directive) so that the `ngRepeat` doesn't have to use any filters.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you store all the data in an array, then filter it only when `fromRow` or `toRow` change?

```
var fullData = $scope.data;
$scope.$watch('fromRow', function(){
        // frowRow minus 1 to get the index
        $scope.data = fullData.splice(fromRow - 1, toRow);
});
```

Comment: since it is bindable data and user is allowed to change data, so it is difficult to syncronize data b/w `data` and `fullData`. It gives more pain than filter.